# how to update request.user in django?

Tags: django, request

I have an ajax call which sets 
`request.user.my_field = value`

When the ajax succeeds, I reload the page with `location.reload(True)`
I expect the `request.user.my_field` in the view function is updated now but it has the old value.

How can I fix this?

EDIT

The ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{% url editor_select %}',
    data: {'editor_type':$(this).val(),
           success: function(response_data) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
               location.reload(true);                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
           }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
          }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
});
```

The first view:

```
def editor_select(request):
    """                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    called when user changes editor type to post question/answer                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    """

    editor_type = CharField().clean(request.POST['editor_type'])
    request.user.editor_type = editor_type
    request.user.save()
```

The second view:

```
def second_view(request):
    print 'ask, editor_type:', request.user.editor_type
```

I find AuthenticationMiddleware (which sets request.user to request), doesn't get called in between the ajax call and the location.reload()

so umm???

Answer (score 5):

Save the model before exiting the view.

```
request.user.save()
```

Comment: I actually do `request.user.save()` in the first view.

Answer (score 0):

Wow shoot me..

`success:` was inside `data` and it requested two pages in succession.